# (click) and [ngClass] not changing table cell color

Tags: angular

Im trying to change the color of a cell within a table once clicked using the following:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <thead>
        <tr style="border: 1px solid black;" *ngFor="let row of tableData">

            <td style="border: 1px solid black;"
                *ngFor="let column of row" class="{{ column }}"
                [ngClass]="{'selected': column == val }"
                [ngClass]="{'toChange': clicked}"
                (click)="clicked = !clicked">
                {{ column | uppercase }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

When each cell is created during the loop, It also has a click event added to it corresponding to the css styling. However, once a cell is clicked I get no change in color at all.

For reference the css is:

```
toChange {
     background-color: blue;
}
```

Anyone care to explain to me why my code doesn't work? Many thanks!

Comment: Your css should be `.toChange` (with the dot in front of it)

Comment: Amended but, I'm still getting no change in color on the clicked cell

Comment: - i updated my answer ... that will work as per you need have look...that will color only selected cell only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have two `[ngClass]` directives. Put them into a single one and separate them with commas like this:

```
[ngClass]="{'selected': column == val, 'toChange': clicked}"
```

Comment: Dunno if I'm pushing my luck here man but do you know any amendments I could do to colour the specifically clicked cell rather than the whole table?

Comment: No, you aren't. But you should formulate that into a new question, as this is too complex to be continued in this comments' section, especially when it comes to posting code snippets. Btw, feel free to mark my answer as solution. Thanks :)

Comment: @JanvanBergen - i updated my answer ... that will work as per you need have look

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[class.toChange]="column == val"
```

Answer (score 1):

one issue might be two `[ngClass]` do like this , you should not have more then on `[ngClass]` on element

```
 <td style="border: 1px solid black;"
                *ngFor="let column of row" class="{{ column }}"
                [ngClass]="{'toChange': clicked, 'selected': column == val }"
                (click)="clicked = !clicked">
                {{ column | uppercase }}
            </td>
```

or you can do like this to make it more readable code

> Below will work as you need as per you comment, only want to color clicked cell
>   `Dunno if I'm pushing
>   my luck here man but do you know any amendments I could do to colour
>   the specifically clicked cell rather than the whole table?`

```
     <td style="border: 1px solid black;"
                    *ngFor="let column of row;let i = index" 
                    [ngClass]="getCssClasses(column,i)"
                    (click)="setClickedIndex(i)">
                    {{ column | uppercase }}
        </td>

 clickedIndex: number;

   setClickedIndex(i){
      this.clickedIndex = i;
   }

    getCssClasses(column,index) {
    let cssClass = column;
    if(column == val)
      cssClass = ' selected';
    if(index===this.clickedIndex) 
       cssClass = ' toChange';
    return cssClass;
    }
```